# sending the 'close' command of a window through my own command?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a wpf application using the MVVM design principle. My ViewModels have a `CloseCommand` that triggers a `RequestClose` event. If the ViewModel is set as the datacontext of a window, the window would subscribe to this event and call `Close()` on itself when the event is triggered.

My problem is that the user can cause a window to close without going through my `RequestClose` system - for instance, by clicking the 'x' at the top right of the window. I want override this, so that clicking the 'x' sends a request to my `CloseCommand`.

I tried attaching this method to the 'Closing' event on my window:

```
void CloseWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var chwn = sender as ChildWindow;
    var dc = chwn.DataContext as AbstractWorkspaceViewModel;
    if (openWindows.Any((wn => dc == wn.DataContext))) {
        if (dc.CloseCommand.CanExecute(null)) {
            dc.CloseCommand.Execute(null);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the chain from `CloseCommand` (after passing through `RequestClose`) ends up calling `window.Close()`, which causes the following error:

```
"Cannot set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog,
 Close, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle while a Window is closing."
```

I guess this is because even though I have written `e.Cancel = true`, the window still thinks its closing until a little later.

I thought about changing my method to look like this:

```
        if (dc.CloseCommand.CanExecute(null))
            dc.CloseCommand.Execute(null);
        else
            e.Cancel = true;
```

and then only calling `window.close()` if the window is not already closing, but I can't work out how to find out if a window is already closing.

How can I resolve this? is it possible to bind the 'x' on the window to my `CloseCommand`?

Comment: How about setting a bool `IsClosing` somewhere in your VM and just keep track of it yourself? Would that work?

Comment: @Default I didn't think of that - I might go with it. Its a bit of a hack though, I'd rather have something else.

Comment: I understand.. I see that there is an `OnClosing` event as well. You might want to trigger the bool from there.

Answer (score 1):

How about set `Window.WindowStyle = "None"` in you Windows XAML (to hide the top buttons and chrome), then add your own 'fake' chrome and buttons that you can wire up as you like

Comment: I thought about doing something like this, but I think it would be really tough to make 'fake' buttons that blend in well with the feel of the OS.

Comment: I would have said it was very easy, but I guess it depends on your knowledge of WPF :)